# Update Multiple List items on change

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, updatelistitems

I have two lists and I am trying to get one to update based on a change from the other, when the titles both match.

Document Library A has a few columns including a date that is updated manually.
[image]

List B has a few unique columns as well as a few that are pulled from Library A
[image]

I have created a WF that updates List B's  "SOP Update Date" when it is changed on Library A
[image]

As you can see in the Image of list B it only updates the first item in the list it finds.   I need it to updates all list items where the title matches that of Library A.

Is this possible on the Workflow 2010 platform?  I do not have access to workflow 2013.

I am open to all possibilities to get this to work, although I am not a programmer I can often tweak code to make it work for me

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 designer workflow, we can using Call HTTP Web Service action with REST API to get all the list items in List B(using $filter in REST Call to filter the data base on the condition), then using the Loop action to update all the list items.

Here is an article for your reference.

[WORKFLOW LOOP THROUGH MULTIPLE SHAREPOINT ITEMS](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to workflow 2013

Comment: In SharePoint 2013, I suggest you set up and configure SharePoint Workflow Manager, then using the workflow 2013 to achieve it. In workflow 2010, there is not OOTB method to achieve it, you need create custom action to achieve it.